# How to GROUP_CONTCAT a COUNT in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that counts all website visitors and groups them by month. So if I run the query, I get 12 rows with the visitors for each month. I want to have them in a php string separated by a comma. I read that this is possible with GROUP_CONCAT. But I don't know how to implement this function in my query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(count_id) FROM counter GROUP BY count_month ORDER BY count_month;
```

Does somebody know how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question is rather why do you need it comma-separated? `GROUP_CONCAT()` might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don’t think GROUP_CONCAT works with the result of aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your query as a subquery

```
select group_concat( my_count)
from (
  SELECT COUNT(count_id) my_count 
  FROM  counter 
  GROUP BY count_month 
  ORDER BY count_month
) t
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!!